# AlreadyLoggedInException in JMeter via XMPP plugin

Tags: authentication, jmeter, xmpp

I try to test the XMPP server through Jmeter with blazemeter XMPP plugin, the plugin is great but I faced some issue.

I need to authenticate two users and start messaging between them (in one thread). After the first user connects to a server and logged in(in the first transaction controller), I create a connection for the second user and trying to log in by this user(in the second transaction controller), but I receive SmackException$AlreadyLoggedInException. (I want to do it in one thread without CSV files like in blazemeter guide).

I found that when I try to create a connection for the second user, in request headers use connection _id and user_data from the first user. In the next sampler which should make the user log in, in response body is correct data, but in the headers using old user_data and new connection_id (from the previous request).

[headers of the second connection request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Kcd.png)

[headers of the second user login request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX65f.png)

I suppose that messaging between two users in one thread is possible, but I'm not sure.

What I'm doing wrong? How I can authenticate two users and start messaging between them?

Answer (score 0):

Messaging between 2 users in one Thread Group is possible, but looking into [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)  I can see only 1 thread (virtual user) started:

[image]

This perfectly explains the situation as in fact you have only 1 connection with 1 thread and trying to use different credentials.

If you're doing some form of a functional test with 1 thread - you will need to disconnect 1st user before connecting the 2nd user.

Otherwise just add one more thread in the Thread Group and [parameterize credentials](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

If you need to implement a "chat" like 2 users talking to each other you can implement "waiting" for responses using i.e. [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)